# in Neo4j my Cypher query pulls data from most recently loaded object, but not the object specified

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I believe this code demonstrates a bug in this software.  But given my lack of experience 
with Neo4j, maybe something is coded incorrectly.  I would like to know if the unexpected output is due to a bug or how I should change my code 
to get the correct output.

Thanks for your help.

[my error text](https://github.com/drum1440/2019/blob/master/Neo4j_error_text.txt)

Answer (score 1):

`MATCH (T8)` matches every node in the database and assigns them to a variable named T8.

I believe you want to use `MATCH (:T8)` to match every node in the database with the label T8.

To delete every node with a T8 label you can use

`MATCH (t:T8) DETACH DELETE (t)`

The `DETACH` portion of the `DELETE` first deletes any relationships in or out of the node and then deletes the node.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have intended to use [node labels](https://neo4j.com/docs/getting-started/3.5/graphdb-concepts/#graphdb-labels)  for your nodes. You only used variables, which just have values within a statement execution. Variable values are not stored in the DB, whereas labels are.

Therefore, in your queries, there is nothing stored in the DB that distinguishes nodes that were referenced using the variable name `T7` from nodes referenced using the variable name `T8`.

Here is an example of a Cypher node pattern with a variable name, `foo`, but no label:

```
(foo)
```

And here is an example with the same variable name and also a label, `Bar`:

```
(foo:Bar)
```

Notice that label names must be preceded by a colon (`:`) within a Cypher node pattern.

Comment: I needed to change my syntax in both the LOAD and the MATCH statement to use label names.

Comment: A "statement" in Cypher refers to an entire query containing one or more "clauses", and `LOAD CSV` and `MATCH` are used to form clauses. Also, a `LOAD CSV` clause has no way to specify indexes.